# Automatic reboot whenever there's an uncaught exception in a continous WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm currently creating a continous webjob that will do polling to an API, and then forward messages to an Azure Service Bus. I've managed to get this to work just fine, but I have one problem; what if my app crashes for whatever reason? What if there's an uncaught exception, or something goes wrong, and the app stops running. How do i get it to run again?

I created a test app, which will send a message every to the Service Bus, then on the 11th message it will crash due to an intentionally placed NullReferenceException. I did this in order to investigate behaviour whenever/if the app crashes.

What happens is that the app runs just fine for the first 10 seconds (as expected). Messages are being sent, and everything looks good. Then after the 10th second, when the exception occurs, nothing happens. No log in Azure saying there was an exception, no reboot - nothing. It just stands there as "running", but messages are no longer being sent.

How do I deal with this? It's essential that the application is able to reboot if it fails. Are there any standard ways to do this? Best practices?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to handle most of the failure scenarios in the system by ourselves rather than to let the hosting environment to react for the failures.

My suggestion would be to have a check in the code for exceptions like any try catch block in your executable script to catch different kind of failure scenarios and instead of throwing the exceptions, log it your self or take any retry operation if required.

Example, when you got a junk data to process and it failed. Then you can try to do the operation again for eg. 3 times and then finally push a log to deadletter  account to manually take care of such junk inputs. And don't let the flow be stopped by throwing the exception but instead handle it your self by logging a message which needs manual intervention.

In any GUI or Web applications, if there is an exception then the flow is re initiated by user click and system will respond. But here as it a background processor, it is ideal to avoid all such control flow blockers.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I agree with everything you're saying. I want to try to catch everything, and handle everything. But the problem is if I do a mistake, resulting in me not catching every exception. There could be overlooked scenarios causing failures which are not accoutned for. This means that there is potential for uncaught exceptions to happen, and I want to know that the app will reboot as a safety-measure whenever this happens.

Comment: Generic exception like System.Exception would handle everything. But to your point to restart the VM on issues, I don't think there is such a way to restart the machine on your own when required that too when an exception occurs in WebJobs.

Comment: I'm not looking to reboot the VM. It's just the app running on the VM. And while I am aware that catching on the top level Exception-object will catch everything, this is not my main concern. My main concern is that an exception occurs outside a try-block, resulting in me not being able to catch it. While this is a somewhat unlikely scenario, but it can technically still happen. Mistakes happen, and I want to make sure that if a mistake does happen - I have a fallback. Sort of like having a backup parachute when you go parajumping.

Comment: But WebJobs are built to be resilient to handle such situaltions marking them as Poinsioned messages. When a junk message comes in, it tries for 5 times (which is configurable) and then it pushes automatically that message to a new queue. Please have a look into WebJobs - How to handle poison messages. This could help you. Ref - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#poison